# Offset in method location

Tags: rascal

I have a location
`|project://SmallSQL/src/smallsql/database/SQLParser.java|(10257,10257,<305,60>,<371,5>)`.

However, because the line `final class SQLParser {` appears to be on line 39, there is an offset of 38, meaning that line 305 actually refers to line 343 (and 371 to 309). I would like to see this offset be reflected in the location. Is that possible, and if so, how? If not, how can I calculate the offset myself?

In addition, the starting line can also be on another location, for example when doc is present before the class. For example in `|project://SmallSQL/src/smallsql/database/ExpressionFunctionBitLen.java|(302,302,<11,25>,<13,2>)`.

Addendum: the locations I am using have been built up by a conversion, i.e., `|java+class:///smallqsl/database/SQLParser|(10257,10257,<305,60>,<371,5>)` was converted to 
`|project://SmallSQL/src/smallsql/database/SQLParser.java|(10257,10257,<305,60>,<371,5>)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `resolveLocation` from the IO module, the offsets will be changed accordingly and properly automatically.

You can also do the resolution yourselves, by looking the right location directly in the M3@declarations table.

```
resolvedLoc = myM3Model@declarations[myLogicalLocation];
```

Comment: O right! You have to have registered the whole m3 model first using registerProject for the resolver to work. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for this information. However, ``resolveLocation(|java+class:///smallqsl/database/SQLParser|(10257,10257,<305,60>,<371,5>))`` gives an error

Comment: I did not use registerProject. Where can I find it? I would have expect it in lang::java::jdt::Project.

Comment: It's in ``analysis::m3::Registry``. I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes. It's called by createm3fromproject as a side effect I believe

Comment: When I use it, what I see is that ``resolveLocation(|java+class:///smallqsl/database/SQLParser|(10257,10257,<305,60>,<371,5>))`` yields ``|file:///C:/Users/olafm/workspace/SmallSQL/src/smallsql/database/SQLParser.java|(10257,2294,<305,60>,<371,5>)``. However this should be ``|file:///C:/Users/olafm/workspace/SmallSQL/src/smallsql/database/SQLParser.java|(11485,2480,<338,4>,<409,5>)``.

Comment: I know this because this -- ``|file:///C:/Users/olafm/workspace/SmallSQL/src/smallsql/data‌​base/SQLParser.java|‌​(11485,2480,<338,4>,‌​<409,5>)``-- is present in what I see when I print the result of createM3FromEclipseProject(). In addition, I can also see in the source code that this is correct.

Comment: That looks like a bug!? Pls register in GitHub issues, if you feel so inclined. Thanks